# Passing arguments to a Nodejs Module using a C++ wrapper?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to develop a better understanding of the technology required to develop Nodejs modules that use a C++ wrapper. I am working through as much information I can find, for example [Nodejs Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). To push my understanding I set the challenge of writing a Nodejs Module that could  be used in a similar way to:

```
var addon = require('./fruit.js');

var apple = new addon.Fruit(5,7);
var pear  = new addon.Fruit(3,6); 

console.log("Apple: weight =  " + apple.getWeight() + " calories = " 
                                + apple.getCalories());

var bunch = new addon.Grapes( 50, 2, 2 );

console.log("Calories of a grape: " + bunch.getCalories());   

console.log("Total weight of grapes: " + bunch.getBunchWeight());
```

where **fruit.js** is:

```
function Fruit(weight, calories) {
   this.weight = weight;
   this.calories = calories;
}

Fruit.prototype.getWeight = function() {
      return this.weight;
};

Fruit.prototype.getCalories = function() {
      return this.calories;
}; 

Grapes.prototype = new Fruit();
Grapes.prototype.constructor=Grapes;
function Grapes(number, weight, calories) {
         this.number=number;
         this.weight=weight;
         this.calories=calories;
}

Grapes.prototype.getTotalWeight = function () {
      return this.number * this.weight;
}

exports.Fruit = Fruit;
exports.Grapes = Grapes;
```

To develop a Nodejs module with a C++ wrapper I worked through a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394176/implementing-inheritance-in-node-js-bindings) posting but when I added parameters to the inherited class the arguments are not being passed to the base class. I have tried a number of solutions but I feel that my understanding about the **Inherit(Handle parent)** function is where I am going wrong. The code is as follows:

**mymod_wrap.h**

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_WRAP_H
#define MYOBJECT_WRAP_H

#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

class Fruit : public node::ObjectWrap {
 public:

    Fruit();
  ~Fruit();

  static Persistent<FunctionTemplate> fruit_template;

  static void Init(Handle<Object> exports);  
  static Handle<Value> New(const Arguments& args);  
  static Handle<Value> GetWeight(const Arguments& args);
  static Handle<Value> GetCalories(const Arguments& args);

private:

   double weight_;
   double calories_;

};

class Grapes : public node::ObjectWrap {

public: 
    Grapes();
    ~Grapes();

    static Persistent<FunctionTemplate> grapes_template;

    static void Init(Handle<Object> exports);
    static Handle<Value> New(const Arguments& args);

    static Handle<Value> GetBunchWeight(const Arguments& args);

private:

    int number_; 

};

#endif
```

**mymod_wrap.cc**

```
#include <node.h>
#include "mymod_wrap.h"

using namespace v8;

Fruit::Fruit() {};
Fruit::~Fruit() {};

void Fruit::Init(Handle<Object> exports) {

  Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(New);

  fruit_template = Persistent<FunctionTemplate>::New(tpl);

  fruit_template->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);  
  fruit_template->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("Fruit"));

  NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(fruit_template, "getWeight", GetWeight);
  NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(fruit_template, "getCalories", GetCalories);

  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("Fruit"), fruit_template->GetFunction());

}

Handle<Value> Fruit::New(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  Fruit* obj = new Fruit(); // Conventional C++ Call see notes

  obj->weight_   = args[0]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : args[0]->NumberValue();
  obj->calories_ = args[1]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : args[1]->NumberValue();

  obj->Wrap(args.This());

  return args.This();
}

Handle<Value> Fruit::GetWeight(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  Fruit* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Fruit>(args.This());

  return scope.Close(Number::New(obj->weight_));
}

Handle<Value> Fruit::GetCalories(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  Fruit* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Fruit>(args.This());

  return scope.Close(Number::New(obj->calories_));

}

Persistent<FunctionTemplate> Fruit::fruit_template;

Grapes::Grapes() {};
Grapes::~Grapes() {};

void Grapes::Init(Handle<Object> exports) {

  Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(New);

  grapes_template = Persistent<FunctionTemplate>::New(tpl);

  grapes_template->Inherit(Fruit::fruit_template);

  grapes_template->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

  grapes_template->SetClassName(String::NewSymbol("Grapes"));

   NODE_SET_PROTOTYPE_METHOD(grapes_template, "getBunchWeight", GetBunchWeight);

  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("Grapes"), grapes_template->GetFunction());

}

Handle<Value> Grapes::New(const Arguments& args ){

      HandleScope scope;

      Grapes* obj = new Grapes();

      obj->number_  = args[0]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : args[0]->NumberValue(); 

      /* the above works but need to pass args[1], args[2] to */
      /*  "weight_" and "calories_" in the base class ?        */

      obj->Wrap(args.This());

      return args.This();

}

Handle<Value> Grapes::GetBunchWeight(const Arguments& args) {

    HandleScope scope;

    Grapes* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Grapes>(args.This());

    /* Need to unwrap the base object to get "weight_" */
    /* multiply with "number_" to get the total weight of the bunch */

    return scope.Close(Number::New( /* return calculated total weight */)); 


}

Persistent<FunctionTemplate>Grapes::grapes_template;
```

**mymod.cc**

```
#include <node.h>

#include "mymod_wrap.h"

using namespace v8;

void InitAll(Handle<Object> exports) {
  Fruit::Init(exports);
  Grapes::Init(exports);
}

NODE_MODULE(fruit, InitAll)
```

I have added a few comments in the code to indicate where I think the problem is.

Grateful for any pointers on where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I think your understanding of the JS side of things has a slight misunderstanding that I want to clear up first.

```
Grapes.prototype = new Fruit();
```

is not a good way to go about this, because that will execute the `Fruit` constructor once and only once with no arguments, even though your `Fruit` function takes two arguments. This effectively does

```
Grapes.prototype.__proto__ = Fruit;
Grapes.prototype.weight = undefined;
Grapes.prototype.calories = undefined;
```

All that you really want is the first line, which is accomplished like this:

```
var util = require('util');
util.inherits(Grapes, Fruit);

// or this if you want to do it manually.
function GrapesProto(){}
GrapesProto.prototype = Fruit;
Grapes.prototype = new GrapesProto();
```

with `Grapes` constructed calling the `Fruit` super constructor.

```
function Grapes(number, weight, calories) {
     this.number = number;

     // Call the 'super' constructor.
     Fruit.call(this, weight, calories);
}
```

Now, with that out of the way, I think it's a little clearer that for you to make this work in C++, `Grapes` should actually extend `Fruit` using standard `C++` inheritance as that is the only way that you can do a correct `super` call.

```
class Grapes : public Fruit {
```

I'd also make your `Grapes` and `Fruit` have non-default constructors that call through to super as the above JS does. You implementation expects each `Grapes` object to have a weight and calories value, and that will not be the case without this. And if you want to be be able to call the inherited template functions from `Fruit` in C++ then it will need to be able to `Unwrap` the `Grapes` object as a `Fruit` which means it needs to be a subclass.

So basically:

```
Handle<Value> Grapes::New(const Arguments& args ){
  double weight  = args[0]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : args[0]->NumberValue(); 
  double calories  = args[1]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : args[1]->NumberValue(); 
  double number  = args[2]->IsUndefined() ? 0 : args[2]->NumberValue(); 
  Grapes* obj = new Grapes(number, weight, calories);

// AND

Grapes::Grapes(int number, double weight, double calories)
  : Fruit(weight, calories), number_(number) {};
```

and pretty much mirror that for `Fruit`.

Comment: Thanks for your great reply to my question. I am new to JS and therefore found your explanation of what is happening in the background very helpful. I worked through your guidance for the C++ implementation, and with a clearer understanding of JS, everything is working. Thanks for your help.